# How can i solve the Array problem in Kotlin?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

When I try to compile some basic array code I get errors. I tried to re-install IntelliJ and I made all updates.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val numbers = intArrayOf(1, 4, 42, -3)
    if (4 in numbers) {
        println("numbers array contains 4.")
    }
}
```

Here are the errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/KotlinPackage
    at KtlneKt.main(ktlne.kt:2)
    at KtlneKt.main(ktlne.kt)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.KotlinPackage
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Is it possible to share the whole project example?

Comment: Kotlin's stdlib is not on the classpath when you run your program. It's hard to tell how to fix this without additional information.

Comment: What kind of additional information should i share ?? @Egor

Comment: @y.bedrov it is the whole project whats written in question. I am new in this lang. and i was writing basic examples to understand the syntax.

Comment: You have to add Kotlin support to your project. Which platform did you use?

Comment: @EnsarBayhan I am using Intellij

Comment: Do you have koltin plugin installed and "Kotlin" facet added to "Project Structure | Modules" ?

Comment: @y.bedrov it says "You have the latest version of the plugin installed."

Comment: How are you trying to run the program?

Comment: @gidds Right click on example.kt and click run 'examplaKt''

Comment: @TolgahanTutar are you using maven or similar? Can you post a screenshot of File> Project Structure

Comment: @PiRocks i am using gradle and here my screenschot http://prntscr.com/p19xbl

Comment: Do you have `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"` or similar in your build.gradle? What about `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.50' `

Comment: Same issue, same question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59522076/1744705). I am facing same issue. I am using Intellij IDEA for pure kotlin (not android) and when I call the intArrayOf() function, compiler throws an error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/KotlinPackage. I think this problem is about Java SDK or Kotlin SDK but I could not figure out which one

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your problem, since you probably want to use intellij. But if you know how to use the command line you could install the kotlin compiler (`kotlinc`) and the run `kotlinc example.kt -include-runtime -d example.jar` and then `java -jar example.jar` to test your code.

Answer (score 0):

[Same question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59522076/1744705) So same answer: I had the same problem and I discovered that this is a bug of Kotlin library. You cannot call `intArrayOf()` method.

I am sure that you are using **Windows 10 Single Language Turkish**. (I was using the same operating system.) Kotlin's some libraries cannot work on Turkish operating system. You can check this issue on [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25400).

You can solve your problem with installing **Windows 10 Pro English** or **Windows 10 Single Language English**. I do not know any other approach right now. (You can open new issue on Kotlin website.)

This bug took from me 30 days. You can check my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59522076/1744705) about this Kotlin bug.

Comment: Just wrote the same code from the question here using gradle and `intArrayOf()` works fine. My guess is that the kotlin-stdlib is not on the classpath.

Comment: Nope @Eduardomacedo . `kotlin-stdlib` is already on the classpath. This is a bug. You can check [Youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25400)

Comment: Well, I believe you. Just thought that is a pretty unique bug and that was unlikely for him to be using the same OS as you.

Comment: Unique bugs take more time to discover. If @Tolgahantutar install Windows 10 Pro English OP, he will see. You can check history of [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59512559/1744705)  about this bug. It takes 30 days and so many contributes.