# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/KotlinPackage & Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.KotlinPackage

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

When I try to add IntArrays in my codes, the Android Studio gives me these errors:

```
"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\idea_rt.jar=50719:C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\bosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-29\android.jar;C:\Users\bosun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-29\data\res;C:\Users\bosun\AndroidStudioProjects\Test2\app\build\intermediates\javac\debug\classes;C:\Users\bosun\AndroidStudioProjects\Test2\app\build\tmp\kotlin-classes\debug;C:\Users\bosun\AndroidStudioProjects\Test2\app\build\generated\res\resValues\debug;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-android-extensions-runtime\1.3.61\289bdf25b4886749e040c7a7d3aab8a57f85c631\kotlin-android-extensions-runtime-1.3.61.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7\1.3.61\70dffc5f8ac5ea7c34f30deac5b9d8b1d48af066\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.61.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.3.61\4702105e97f7396ae41b113fdbdc180ec1eb1e36\kotlin-stdlib-1.3.61.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.3.61\65abb71d5afb850b68be03987b08e2c864ca3110\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.61.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.collection\collection\1.0.0\42858b26cafdaa69b6149f45dfc2894007bc2c7a\collection-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.lifecycle\lifecycle-common\2.0.0\e070ffae07452331bc5684734fce6831d531785c\lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.arch.core\core-common\2.0.0\bb21b9a11761451b51624ac428d1f1bb5deeac38\core-common-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.annotation\annotation\1.0.2\2f1d597d48e5309e935ce1212eedf5ae69d3f97\annotation-1.0.2.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\4400ce52558a1326f6f8df052592e334\core-ktx-1.0.2\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\879984f11f327e0566da31edd3b93778\appcompat-1.0.2\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\879984f11f327e0566da31edd3b93778\appcompat-1.0.2\res;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\9ac1dcdf45a51c129ec9ab070abfd8d7\fragment-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\9b9150b07929bc69439efe995438be41\vectordrawable-animated-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\59d04c87522e7722ea3ca8715a8b0d7d\legacy-support-core-ui-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\e8e43754c06475d8590f4ff699e532f8\legacy-support-core-utils-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\f918a2c43bb058b74c18b9596e2a2796\vectordrawable-1.0.1\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d1a473dd41ab9d9cfedb415a767fa8e2\loader-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\28a2f2bfe5b19437baae53dd908102d9\viewpager-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ced0565cf77ede6c9fe2cc907e012eb2\coordinatorlayout-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ced0565cf77ede6c9fe2cc907e012eb2\coordinatorlayout-1.0.0\res;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0e17e0903cc4b356cac1f1cdb05efef6\drawerlayout-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3bb2c7104f2f4e21e4344de7d5162af7\slidingpanelayout-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\e4f940674933431d2ed1592b500f2e4e\customview-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\4cc9299baa04d807d8b5ed7d258aef09\swiperefreshlayout-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\70edb5ab10f0c6baaf068d26450280d2\asynclayoutinflater-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\bde5344dd836d92b3a6c11207c599e3d\core-1.0.2\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\bde5344dd836d92b3a6c11207c599e3d\core-1.0.2\res;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1df4b1ae03d2b473d0219ecebc547a11\versionedparcelable-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a5cd9e8e0d405c18c2b2d3ee49201e52\cursoradapter-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\4ec2bbfd3859804671a6ce6c91e03a8c\documentfile-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\9d992e7c041153936c4b20c6e9d00821\localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\99907df3d56060bc7b1502dcd5ee124b\print-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\99a636cd82617c988188441746e7f20d\lifecycle-viewmodel-2.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\c20fb0ee45b96eb0e4b0a639b2ec1f4d\lifecycle-runtime-2.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\7b586029e966589a4a60caf5a0a6e9d2\interpolator-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d94f7826feb0de043e3c43244f79749a\lifecycle-livedata-2.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\e31b9daaaa8bb7510409960c20556b7e\lifecycle-livedata-core-2.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\bosun\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\373d10fc23cf87276d7fbe4eda833447\core-runtime-2.0.0\jars\classes.jar com.example.test2.MainKt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/KotlinPackage
    at com.example.test2.MainKt.main(main.kt:4)
    at com.example.test2.MainKt.main(main.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.KotlinPackage
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

Most codes works fine. I can test some projects. Emulator is working fine too. But when it comes to add IntArrays it cannot compile. I've search on everywhere but I couldn't find the solution. I've reinstalled the Android Studio and JRE but it didn't work as well.

Used Codes:

```
package com.example.test2

fun main(){
    var a:IntArray = intArrayOf(1,2,3,4)
    println("test")
}
```

My build Gradles:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and the second one is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

}
```

Addition: I have tested this situation in a completely different computer. It gives an error too. I guess it is kind a bug of Android Studio.

Comment: "var a:IntArray = intArrayOf(1,2,3,4)" to "var a = intArrayOf(1,2,3,4)".... remove ":IntArray"

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: that doesn't look like an android activity to me, what exactly are you trying to achieve? my guess is that you got android all wrong, try adding an (auto-generated) activity and see how its coded.

Comment: Can you try to compile a project which has IntArrays in it ? I have projects which contains activites. I know what activity is. The thing is I faced this problem when it comes to use IntArrays. So, I decided to test it with "no empty" project. But it is failure.

Comment: I am facing same issue. I am using Intellij IDEA for pure kotlin (not android) and when I call the `intArrayOf()` function, compiler throws an error : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/KotlinPackage`. I think this problem is about Java SDK or Kotlin SDK but I could not figure out which one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and I discovered that this is a bug of Kotlin library. (I am so serious.) You cannot call `intArrayOf()` method.

I am sure that you are using Windows 10 Single Language **Turkish**. (I was using the same operating system.) Kotlin's some libraries cannot work on Turkish operating system. You can check this issue on [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25400).

You can solve your problem with installing **Windows 10 Pro English** or **Windows 10 Single Language English**. I do not know any other approach right now. (You can open new issue on Kotlin website.)

This bug took from me 30 days. You can check [my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59512559/1744705) about this Kotlin bug.